# Search document in mongoid by Object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a collection in mongodb to store Participants. The data goes like:

> ```
>     { 
>      "_id" : ObjectId("53badeee6d6179191f030000"), 
>
>     "user_id" : ObjectId("53b619a16d6179141e000000"),
>
>     "campaign_id" : ObjectId("53b82c246d617912a9040000") 
>     }
> ```

Now how do I search it from rails?

```
@participant=Participant.find(user_id:current_user_id, campaign_id:params[:id])
```

--This does not work. Should I always create objects like : `ObjectId("53b82c246d617912a9040000")`

Participant model:

```
class Participant
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :detail, type: String
  field :date, type: Date
  belongs_to(:user)
  belongs_to(:campaign)

  validates_uniqueness_of :user, :scope => [:campaign]
end
```

Am i doing something wrong by design itself? Please suggest.

Comment: Please post your model so we can get a sense of the relationships between user, campaign and participant.

Comment: http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/finders.html

Comment: it should be something like `Participant.where(user_id: current_user_id)`

Comment: @muistooshort please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
@participant = Participant.where(
  user_id: current_user_id,
  campaign_id: params[:id]
).first
```

or

```
@participant = Participant.where(
  user_id: current_user.id, # as i suspect you are using devise current user
  campaign_id: params[:id]
).first
```

and it should work. also make sure that the `params[:id]` contains an existing `campaign_id` and you are not searching with the wrong parameter (`params[:campaign]` for example)